# ActionScript Cue Points for closed captioning in Video control?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, closed-captions

I am using using Flash Builder to create an AS3 video player which needs to support Closed Captioning. However, I am not using the FLVPlayback component.  Is there a way of doing something like addASCuePoint() to flash.media.Video;, or is my only option using Flash's Timer to do my own check?

I would imagine there must be lib out there that handles this but i can't find one anywhere.

Also, the solution must work with flash player 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple cue manager class that holds your cue points and observes the video position.

Observe the NetStream.time value every frame and find the current cue point.

You could have it dispatch an event when it reaches a new cue point, and your view could change state.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually the way that i went about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the OSMF framework

http://osmf.org/

check R. Blank's site for more info, code & samples

http://www.rblank.com/

Comment: I was planning on using that, but i was under the impression it only worked on Flash Player 10 and up. Or is that just the dynamic streaming capabilities?

Comment: You're right , I don't think OSMF is compatible with FP 9, this being said FP10 has been out for quite a while now.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the business requirements ask for FP 9. Already tried to pitch FP 10 :(